# Is Flux a library which operates as the backend for React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sails.js, flux

I'm very new to the React and Flux consept and I'm *confused as hell..*

I come from a background of [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) so I can't really tell whats what with React.

I plan to use [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) (**as a restful api, isolated from the front end**) 
+
[React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) (**as my front end using restful calls + perhaps websockets to communicate with sails**)

but I don't see where flux fits in!

Comment: The docs cover this: https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html. It's also where much of the answer below came from. It's just client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flux is definitely not a requirement for using React and does not operate as a "back-end" for React. It's just a common pattern for structuring applications written with React. It's well documented [here](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html#content).

It is only a client side solution. It does not have a hard requirement on any particular web server (but it is convenient if you have NodeJS installed so that you can use something like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) to compile and package scripts).

It's not clear from your question what parts of Sails you're planning to use. If you want to use React in an *isomorphic* way (meaning you'd run React code on the web server and it would be then "attached" by the React client code, without re-rendering), then data management could be an issue if you're using [Waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline). But, if you're only going to use React on the client, then it may be an easier integration.

But, again, it's not necessary to use Flux. You can just follow the basic principles of using React JS regarding data flow (parent to child) and use other data storage and synchronization libraries. React is not opinionated that way.

Also, while Facebook has a Flux implementation [here](https://github.com/facebook/flux), you'll find dozens of implementations of the pattern with various tweaks and enhancements located [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/wiki/Complementary-Tools#model-management). You'll also note on that same page that there are lots of other complimentary libraries that may be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I changed my question to better describe what I plan to do: I plan to use Sails.js (as a restful api, isolated from the front end) + React (as my front end using restful calls + perhaps websockets to communicate with sails)

Comment: OK ... is there something that wasn't covered in the answers though? Flux doesn't have to fit in at all into your application. It's just an option that some developers like to use. I've found it to be a poor fit in some apps.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Flux is a [**design pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns), rather than a framework or library. You can use Flux without using React and vice versa, although they are optimized to work well with each other.

Flux applications have three major parts: the `Dispatcher`, the `Stores`, and the `Views` (not be confused with [**Model-View-Controller**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)). [**EventEmitter**](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter) is typically used as a basis for `Stores` and [**React**](https://facebook.github.io/react/) as a basis for `Views`. The one piece of Flux not readily available elsewhere is the [**Dispatcher**](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/dispatcher.html), although you could write one yourself if you want.

`Controllers` do exist in a Flux application, but they are **controller-views** -- `Views` often found at the top of the hierarchy that retrieve data from the stores and pass this data down to their children. Additionally, action creators — dispatcher helper methods — are often used to support a semantic dispatcher API.

Flux eschews MVC in favor of a unidirectional data flow. When a user interacts with a React view, the view propagates an `Action` through a central `Dispatcher`, to the various `Stores` that hold the application's data and business logic, which updates all of the views that are affected. While you don't need React to implement this pattern per se, it is designed to work especially well with React's declarative programming style, which allows the store to send updates without specifying how to transition views between states.

More info can be found at the [**official Flux repo**](https://github.com/facebook/flux).

[image]

Comment: So a typical scenario for a web app would be, 1. a restful api as a backend, 2. flux+React as front end right? Flux+react is just front end correct?

Comment: @SudoPlz : The official implementation of Flux does rely on Node.js, which means that it isn't a pure frontend implementation. On the other hand, you should be able to implement Flux completely on frontend, using pure frontend equivalents like https://github.com/Wolfy87/EventEmitter.

Comment: @JohnSlegers-what is the official Flux implementation? A Facebook implementation is available via NPM, but it doesn't need or require NodeJS to execute at run time.

Comment: @WiredPrairie : The official implementation is the one at https://github.com/facebook/flux and relies on Node.js's EventEmitter class. Maybe NPM can install if for you behind your back (?), but NPM isn't present on most non-Node.js systems either.

Comment: Regardless, it doesn't change that Flux is not a backend. It's purely client side. It would be also great if you were to reference where you got the images and much of the text from your answer.

Comment: @WiredPrairie : I got the info from the official Flux repo, which I linked to at the end. And yes, Flux itself is purely client side, however, I'm pretty sure it isn't possible to get the official repo to work running in a non-Node.js environment. I can't find any reference to the dependency on EventEmitter in either package.json or bower.json, yet Flux's official implementation of Stores is based on the EventEmitter. Still, pure client side implementations that don't rely on Node.js do exist. https://github.com/rbtech/react-flux-js-lib would be a good example.

Comment: @JohnSlegers - why is Node a problem? Sails is a NodeJS server/client framework.

Comment: @WiredPrairie : NodeJS isn't always an option for the type of projects I'm working on. For example, I often use low cost shared servers with a LAMP stack where I'm not allowed to install NodeJS.

Comment: OK -- but I don't see how that's relevant to the question. It still is pure-front end and requires a one-time bundling.

Comment: @WiredPrairie : If it requires a NodeJS stack, it doesn't qualify as a pure frontend solution IMO.

Comment: (OK, but as an example, even jQuery requires Node for compilation. :)  https://github.com/jquery/jquery#what-you-need-to-build-your-own-jquery)

Comment: @WiredPrairie : For editing the source code and building your own custom distri of libraries like jQuery or D3, you do indeed need NodeJS. If you just want to use the official distri of those libraries as an end user (which probably applies to >99% of their use base), you don't need NodeJS at all. You can use jQuery, D3 and many other frontend libraries out of the box without having to install Node.js or NPM. This doesn't apply to Flux.